Siemens 97371-132 keyboard on PS/2: How do I make the special keys emit a scancode?
I've got a Siemens 97371-132 / S26381-K99-V820 "tri-modal" keyboard, built in 1994, with PS/2 interface. Such keyboards were used both on Siemens PCs, as well as midrange machines running the Sinix OS, and the 97000 series of terminals attached to BS/2000-based mainframes. Now I'm about to test the board on a Linux PC (OpenSuSE Leap 15.5 with KDE). Almost all keys, which are also present on common MF2 keyboards, work well, but some keys apparently do not emit any scancodes. These problematic keys are:

The big Menu key under the Return key.
The F15, F16, as well as F18 thru F22 keys.
Several keys located beneath the row of F keys: Mode, Ch.Code, Print, Insert Word, Insert Line, Start, End, the three Delete keys, as well as an unlabelled key just left of Num Lock.
A numpad key labelled with an equals sign.

How can I make these keys "work", which means, emit scancodes? Mode and Ch.Code are possibly linked to keyboard-internal functions, but I can't find any changes on the scancodes of the other keys when I press one of these keys.

After a valuable hint I executed evtest on the "silent" keys and got the following (here from the CH.CODE and MODE keys, respectively):
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  sudo evtest /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd                                    130 ↵
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x1 product 0x1 version 0xab41
Input device name: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    // Remainder of keycode list omitted.
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
  Event type 17 (EV_LED)
    Event code 0 (LED_NUML) state 1
    Event code 1 (LED_CAPSL) state 0
    Event code 2 (LED_SCROLLL) state 0
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1733946407.693845, type 17 (EV_LED), code 0 (LED_NUML), value 0
Event: time 1733946407.693845, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 1c
Event: time 1733946407.693845, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 28 (KEY_ENTER), value 0
Event: time 1733946407.693845, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
// Remainder of key tests omitted.
// Key CH.CODE
Event: time 1733946475.906925, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 64
Event: time 1733946475.906925, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733946476.064745, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 64
Event: time 1733946476.064745, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
// Key MODE
Event: time 1733946478.911207, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 66
Event: time 1733946478.911207, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1733946479.050291, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 66
Event: time 1733946479.050291, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------

What I can already see is that the keys in question do emit some data, which unfortunately do not map to a key press and release event. Instead, I only get a type 4 event. The desired type 1 event is missing, though. What does MSC_SCAN denote BTW?

Are you using the PS/2 connector or do you use a converter to USB? Most of them will refuse to convert scan codes unknown to the PC.

@tofro More like, the converter itself does not understand the unkown scancodes, and does not know what to send to PC over USB, even if such a button is specified on USB like F13..F24 are. It's likely that the keyboard needs to be set into some specific scancode set to output anything from the non-PC keys. If possible, checking if the keyboard sends anything at all, and if it does then what, could be seen on a logic analyzer or an oscilloscope.

@tofro I still have a "real" PS/2 jack on my PC. What I cannot exclude, though, is that there is an on-board PS/2-to-USB converter present.

xev on a Linux system could help in getting the low-level key codes.

@tofro xev is exactly the tool I'm using!

If you can plug the keyboard into a DOS machine, KB at https://www.seasip.info/DOS/ can report the scancodes sent when particular keys are pressed (and select set 1 / set 2 / set 3 scancodes). If you don't get a response from the keys in that scenario, they may require a custom command sent from the host to the keyboard to activate them - it wouldn't be easy to work out what, without documentation or a microcode dump.

Have you checked whether there's a mode switch, e.g. under the foil wrapper?

https://forum.classic-computing.de/forum/index.php?user-post-list/3644-xenolog/

Little titbit, tri-modal keyboards were only sold for/used with PCs, not terminals, as Sinix/BS2000 terminal had their own keyboard versions. Tri-modal were for the use case of PC's running terminal programs for Sinix  or BS2000 host systems. For the question, best test environment might be some Arduino and some basic PS/2 software decoding and forwarding all received data as text via USB (serial emulation). That way it should be rather easy to see what is send.

Also, are you sure it's a PS/2? In my memory (and the order tables) the -V820 is an AT variant originally introduced with the PCD-2 series. Also it's not tri-modal, but only DOS/SINIX, missing all BS2000 relevant labelling.  It might be helpful to add a picture of keyboard and connectors

PS/2 and AT keyboards use the same protocol on the wire - the only difference is the physical connector.

One after the other: The KB will be attached to a serial terminal board like this one: https://www.hackster.io/news/fabrizio-di-vittorio-s-fabgl-project-gets-a-serial-terminal-board-with-ttl-and-rs232-connectivity-15465c850f07 AFAIK, this board is equipped with a "real" PS/2 KB port, not an emulated one. And yes, I know that older battlecruiser KBs sometimes had keys, which triggered local actions like the programming of a macro, but the F and Delete keys to certainly not belong into this category.

As for my memory, it's really just a dumb keyboard, transmitting all keys as they are pressed. CH.Code for example switches character code interpretation of the terminal (emulation) between 7/8 bit code sets and within between country specific ASCII variants or ISO8859 variants (The 97801 variants were quite nice to cope with all the 7/8 bit code chaos). Nothing a keyboard could do on it's own. Same for mode.

Good hint, @Raffzahn! When pressing the Mode key, I realised that a small handful of keys started emitting key press & key release events: Insert Word (now suddenly impersonating PrtSc, so that I've now got two keys with the same scancode!), Start, and End.

After a handful of really useful answers and comments and upon reading the tutorial Map scancodes to keycodes in the Arch Linux wiki, I found out that the solution given in § 3 is the right one (and the easiest one): The setkeycodes utility allows to map scancodes to keycodes, so it is sufficient to call the program like this:
sudo /usr/bin/setkeycodes 5e 183 5f 184 63 185 62 186 5d 187 6a 188 74 189 77 190 76 191 6b 192 64 112 66 116 5c 127 6c 226 71 117 75 164 68 128 67 95 6f 91 6d 85 65 157

…and then to define and activate a systemd service to make these mappings take effect upon boot. I also managed to map the keys F13 thru F22 to the corresponding keycodes #186 thru #192, even if they originally did not appear in the output of evtest.
UPDATE: Here is an explanation of what the numbers in the setkeycodes represent:
Key     |Scancode|Keycode|Mnemonic
========|========|=======|==================
F13     |5e      |183    |KEY_F13
F14     |5f      |184    |KEY_F14
F15     |63      |185    |KEY_F15
F16     |62      |186    |KEY_F16
F17     |5d      |187    |KEY_F17
F18     |6a      |188    |KEY_F18
F19     |74      |189    |KEY_F19
F20     |77      |190    |KEY_F20
F21     |76      |191    |KEY_F21
F22     |6b      |192    |KEY_F22
Ch.Code |64      |112    |KEY_MACRO
Mode    |66      |116    |KEY_POWER
Print   |65      |157    |KEY_COMPUTER
Del.Char|6f      |91     |KEY_HIRAGANA
Del.Word|6d      |85     |KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU
Start   |75      |164    |KEY_PLAYPAUSE
End     |68      |128    |KEY_STOP
(none)  |67      |95     |KEY_KPJPCOMMA
CE      |5c      |127    |KEY_COMPOSE
Equals  |71      |117    |KEY_KPEQUAL
Menu    |6c      |226    |KEY_MEDIA

But: Making these keys useful under X.org is another question.

Great job. It might be a good idea to add a table listing all those scan keys/assignment/basic data, making this answer useful for future readers stumbling across one of those keyboards.

No need to run a systemd service. Just add a /etc/udev/rules.d/ file which uses RUN+= to run setkeycodes  on hotplug.

Partial answer:
Linux has two key translation layers, one from raw devices to the kernel input layer, one from the kernel input layer to the X event layer.
Both layers use "scan codes", you didn't say which layer you checked.
Assuming you connected the keyboard to PC hardware that actually has a PS/2 connector (and not some USB simulation etc.), you can see the codes emitted from the keyboard by dumping
/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd

If the keys you mention don't emit anything there when pressed, then likely you need to somehow configure the keyboard to enable those keys. This will be very difficult to figure out.
Assuming the keys emit something there, you have the raw press and release codes.
You can inspect the output of the kernel translation layer with
evtest /dev/input/eventX

or
evtest /dev/input/by-path/...

where you have to figure out the right device (simplest option is often just trying them out, but you can also read the syslog).
If your keys emit nothing on this layer, you need to make a custom keyboard layout for the kernel.
The final X layer can be tested with xev. If your keys emit something on the lower layers, but nothing on this layer, you need to make a custom X keyboard layout (see xmodmap, setxkbmap, xkbcomp etc., see An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration for a good introduction).

EV_MSC is the miscellaneous event class, MSC_SCAN denotes a raw scancode event in this class.
So you are getting scancode 64 for Ch.Code and scancode 66 for Mode.
You need to write a custom kernel layer keyboard mapping to translate those, as they are non-standard. See man 5 keymaps, man loadkeys, and have a look at existing mappings in /usr/share/keymaps (if available on your distribution) or /usr/src/linux/drivers/char/defkeymap.map after installing the linux kernel source.
Depending on where you map those scancodes to, you still may need a custom X keyboard mapping.

I suppose that xev works on the X event layer. And when I mean that the key emits no scancode, I don't get an X event at all.

Then please do check the two lower layers to see if you get anything.

Thank you for the hint. See the update above for results.
